# Ag-grid does not support Date Time Filter

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I want to implement a date-time filter on ag-grid column. But ag-grid does not support the date-time filter.
My date-time format is DD/MM/YY HH:MM:SS
Is there any way I can modify the 'agDateColumnFilter' to support DateTime or I have to write a custom date-time filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to modify the `agDateColumnFilter` using 3rd party components. You can see two examples [in the documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-date-component/) and a [blog post](https://blog.ag-grid.com/using-third-party-datepickers-in-ag-grid/).

A few things to note:

1. You'll still have to declare a custom framework component to replace the default filter. That component will render the 3rd party component.
2. You need to append the component to `document.body`. Otherwise, it will be contained in the filter `<div>` and it'll look funny.

   [image]
3. You'll also have to set `"ag-custom-component-popup"` as one of it's classes, so that clicking on the date picker does not close the filter window.